# need to delete child nodes based on parent node id using mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql

**Question:**

I need to delete child nodes based on parent node id. So please help me.

**Note:**

This below stored procedure i made for selecting child nodes based on parent node id.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Hierarchy`(IN `GivenID` INT, IN `initial` INT)
BEGIN

    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE next_id INT;
    -- CURSOR TO LOOP THROUGH RESULTS --
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT GID FROM civicsoft_group WHERE Parent_Group_ID = GivenID;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;
    -- CREATE A TEMPORARY TABLE TO HOLD RESULTS --
    IF initial=1 THEN
        -- MAKE SURE TABLE DOESN'T CONTAIN OUTDATED INFO IF IT EXISTS (USUALLY ON ERROR) --
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS OUT_TEMP; 
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE OUT_TEMP (TGID int,TParent_Group_ID int, TGroup_Name varchar(32),TGroup_Type varchar(1),TProject_Status tinyint(1),TEID int,TEmp_Group_ID int,TEmp_Name varchar(100),TEmp_Type varchar(2));
    END IF;

    -- ADD OURSELF TO THE TEMPORARY TABLE --
    INSERT INTO OUT_TEMP SELECT cg.GID,cg.Parent_Group_ID,cg.Group_Name,cg.Group_Type,cg.Project_Status,ce.EID,ce.Emp_Group_ID,ce.Emp_Name,ce.Emp_Type FROM civicsoft_group cg LEFT JOIN civicsoft_employee ce ON cg.GID = ce.Emp_Group_ID  WHERE cg.GID = GivenID;

    -- AND LOOP THROUGH THE CURSOR --
    OPEN cur1;
    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur1 INTO next_id;

        -- NO ROWS FOUND, LEAVE LOOP --
        IF done THEN
        LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        -- NEXT ROUND --

    SET @@GLOBAL.max_sp_recursion_depth = 255;
    SET @@session.max_sp_recursion_depth = 255; 

        CALL Hierarchy(next_id, 0);     
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE cur1;

    -- THIS IS THE INITIAL CALL, LET'S GET THE RESULTS --
    IF initial=1 THEN
SELECT * FROM OUT_TEMP;
        -- CLEAN UP AFTER OURSELVES --
        DROP TABLE OUT_TEMP; 
    END IF;
END
```

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: i want to delete child nodes based on parent node id. i made above stored procedure for selection only. But for deletion i don't know how to do. plz help me. i am new in mysql stored procedure

Comment: even i copied this procedure from internet only.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be, if you added a foreign key to your child table referencing the parent table. This also works when parent and child are in the same table. Enable the `ON DELETE CASCADE` option in this foreign key. Then just delete the parent entry and MySQL will delete the children for you, too.

Comment: see frnd i am having parent and child in different table then how

Comment: I said it **also** works when they are in the same table. This means that it especially works when they are in different tables. I pointed you in the right direction. This is no code write service or anything, we encourage you to learn something, not how to best copy&paste. Do some research, it's not hard.

Comment: hi frnd, i want to update parent id of child node as empty and parent node should get delete, when passing parent id